# How to filter overlap rows in a big file with R

Tags: r, overlap

I am trying to filter overlap rows in a big file with R.The overlap degrees is set as 25%. In other words,the number of element of intersection between any two rows is less than 0.25 times of union of them.if more than 0.25,one row is deleted.So if I have a big file with 1000 000 rows in total, the first 5 rows are as follows:

> c6 c24 c32 c54 c67
>   c6 c24 c32 c51 c68 c78
>   c6 c32 c54 c67
>   c6 c32 c55 c63 c85 c94 c75
>   c6 c32 c53 c67

Because the number of element of intersection between the 1st row and 2nd row is 3,(such as c6,c24,c32 ),the number of union between them is 8,(such as c6,c24,c32,c54,c67,c51,c68,c78),3/8=0.375 > 0.25,the 2nd row is deleted.so do the 3rd and 5th rows.The final answer is the 1st and 4th row.

> c6 c24 c32 c54 c67
>   c6 c32 c55 c63 c85 c94 c75

the pseudo code as follows:

> ```
> for i=1:(n-1)    # n is the number of rows of a file
>     for j=(i+1):n  
>         if  overlap degrees of the ith row and jth row is more than 0.25
>           delete the jth row from the file
>         end
>    end
> ```
>
> end

the R code are as follows:

> ```
>    con<-file("inputfile.txt","r")
>    fileConn<-file("outputfile025.txt")
>    data<-readLines(con,n=1) 
>    con1<-strsplit(data,"\t") 
>    writeLines(con1[[1]][], fileConn)
>
>    for(i in 2:1000000){
>    data<-readLines(con,n=1) 
>    con2<-strsplit(data,"\t")
>
>     intersect=length(intersect(con1[[1]][],con2[[1]][]))
>     union =length(union(con1[[1]][],con2[[1]][]))
>
>    if ((intersect/union)<0.25){
>     writeLines(con2[[1]][], fileConn)
>    }
>
>    }
>    close(con)
>    close(fileConn)
> ```

The problem is that the above code can only be used to filter overlap between the 1st rows and any other rows, how to filter overlap between the 2nd,3rd,...... rows and any other rows. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: It's not really clear to me... After the first row is compared to all others, do you want to compare the second row to all others? Then the third row? If yes, notd that the final output will depend on the order of compared rows. E.g. the output of comparing rows 1, 2, 3 may be different if you compare the rows in order 1, 3, 2

Comment: You could use `expand.grid` to get row combinations (beware of duplicates) and loop through that.

Comment: I am not sure your problem is well specified. For example, after you filter the file with comparisons to the first row, will you start over with the now trimmed file? Or will the comparison with the second row be another output file?

Comment: I added some explanation about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using `agrep` that approximate matches to pattern (here one element of your list ) within other elements of the list using the generalized Levenshtein edit distance:

```
max.distance=list(deletions=0.25)
```

So looping through your data using `lapply` for example:

```
res <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(ll),function(x){
  res <- agrep(pattern=ll[x],         # for each string
              ll[-x],                # I search between the others strings 
              value=FALSE,max=list(deletions=0.25))  # I set the Levenshtein distance
  if(length(res)==0) NA else res
}))
ll[res[!is.na(res) & duplicated(res)]]

"c6 c24 c32 c54 c67"         
"c6 c32 c54 c67"             
"c6 c32 c55 c63 c85 c94 c75"
```

Then you can remove duplicated and missing values :

PS : here `ll` is :

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection(object='c6 c24 c32 c54 c67
c6 c24 c32 c51 c68 c78
c6 c32 c54 c67
c6 c32 c55 c63 c85 c94 c75
c6 c32 c53 c67'))
```

Comment: I added some explanation about my problem.

Comment: @user2405694 Your pseudo code is not clear. Do you want to compare 1 to others than 2 to others[-1], 3  to others[-c(1,2)],..?

Comment: @user2405694 Well So do you want to do this :  `1 to others ; 2 to others[-c(1,overlapped1)]; 3 to others[-c(1,2,overlapped1,overlapped2)]`,..? –